# matplotlib.animation: script works under Windows, and works under Linux for short animations, but hangs indefinitely for longer animations?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, debian

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, outputFiles, blit=True, interval=25)

print "Starting to write animation file..."
# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']

fps = 2
animationFileName = "animation"
if fps <= 2:
    animationFileName = animationFileName + "_slow.mp4"
if fps < 120:
    animationFileName = animationFileName + ".mp4"
else:
    animationFileName = animationFileName + "_fast.mp4"

writer = Writer(fps=fps, metadata=dict(artist='Alien'), bitrate=1800)
ani.save(os.path.join(graphicsOutputDirectory, animationFileName), writer=writer)
print "Finished writing animation file..."
```

When running the script in Linux (Debian Wheezy), I see the following output:

```
>>> python make_animation.py
Starting to run animation file...
```

In Windows, the script runs just fine. I have made sure that I am not making silly errors like using incorrect file names. Short animations seem to run just fine on my GNU/Linux machine and longer more serious ones seem to hang indefinitely...

What might the issue here be? I suppose a relevant detail I should mention is that I am using a virtualenvironment to run an up-to-date version of matplotlib.

Comment: can you provide enough code to reproduce the problem?  I have never had problems on linux + py2k.

Comment: @tcaswell I am not sure I would be able to do that in a manner that is also readable...I wonder if the issue has to do with perhaps the 'ffmpeg' matplotlib animation writers not being (generally) safe on GNU/Linux? Perhaps I should be using another one? I posted a question in that vein here, but it seems to have been thoroughly misunderstood: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334952/matplotlib-animation-gnu-linux-safe-animation-writers

Comment: To my knowledge the ffmpeg writers are fine in linux, I don't really know what you mean by 'not safe'.  There are some known issues with python 3k and pipes (which are used in the ffmpeg writers).  With out an example that behaves badly, there is not much anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Debian now ship with deprecated FFMPEG versions. That may be the issue. Try replacing the ffmpeg binary in your /usr/bin by a recent one from the FFMPEG website.

Another possible issue concerns Python 3, in which subprocess has a smaller buffer and will hang forever if ffmpeg sends too much informations back to Python. Are you on Python 3 ?

Comment: @Zulko I am not on Python 3. I think you are right that this might be the issue. Plus, I have found others who are having the problem too: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/matplotlib-FuncAnimation-hanging-issue-td41002.html

Comment: @tcaswell See above comment -- I think this has something to do with the ffmpeg writer ignoring "quiet" settings. Perhaps because of deprecated FFMPEG versions?